# Mail only being sent once inside php while loop

Tags: php, email

I have a simple problem that is driving me crazy.

Review the code below; I am essentially trying to send a mass mailing out with addresses from a database.

The problem is that only one message, for the first record is being sent out. I have verified (via a counter and concatenation of text) that the loop goes through for every record.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

```
function SendMassMailing($Connection, $MailingID) {

    $select_query = "SELECT `Drafts`.`SentMailingID`, `Drafts`.`FromAddress`, `Drafts`.`BCCFromAddress`, `Drafts`.`AdditionalBCC`, `Categories`.`MailingUserCategoryID`, `Drafts`.`Subject`,`Drafts`.`Message`, `Drafts`.`Notes`, `Drafts`.`DateCreated`
                        FROM `MailingDraftSent` AS `Drafts`
                        INNER JOIN `MailingUserCategories` AS `Categories`
                        ON `Drafts`.`MailingUserCategoryID` = `Categories`.`MailingUserCategoryID`
                        WHERE `Drafts`.`SentMailingID` = $MailingID ORDER BY `Drafts`.`DateCreated` DESC;";

    $select_result = mysqli_query($Connection, $select_query);

    if (!$select_result) {

        die(mysqli_error($select_result));

    }

    $main_message_row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $from = $main_message_row['FromAddress'];

    $CategoryID = $main_message_row['MailingUserCategoryID'];

    $subject = $main_message_row['Subject'];;

    $headers = "From: ".$from." <" . $from . ">\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $message = $main_message_row['Message'];

    mysqli_free_result($select_result);

    $select_query = "SELECT `MailingUserCategoryID`, `UserCategoryQuery` FROM `MailingUserCategories` WHERE `MailingUserCategoryID` = $CategoryID;";

    $select_result = mysqli_query($Connection, $select_query);

    if (!$select_result) {

        die(mysqli_error($select_result));

    }

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($select_result) > 0 ) {

        $query_row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $query_to_run = $query_row['UserCategoryQuery'];

        $query_to_run = UnsanitizeQuery($query_to_run);

        mysqli_free_result($select_result);

        $select_result = mysqli_query($Connection, $query_to_run);

        if (!$select_result) {

            die(mysqli_error($select_result));

        }

        if ( mysqli_num_rows($select_result) > 0 ) {

            $MessageCount = 0;

            $originalmessage = $message;
            $originalsubject = $subject;

            while ($person_message_row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                $message = str_replace("[[FullName]]", $person_message_row['FirstName']." ".$person_message_row['LastName'], $originalmessage);
                $subject = str_replace("[[FullName]]", $person_message_row['FirstName']." ".$person_message_row['LastName'], $originalsubject);
                $message = str_replace("[[FirstName]]", $person_message_row['FirstName'], $message);
                $subject = str_replace("[[FirstName]]", $person_message_row['FirstName'], $subject);
                $message = str_replace("[[LastName]]", $person_message_row['LastName'], $message);
                $subject = str_replace("[[LastName]]", $person_message_row['LastName'], $subject);
                $message = str_replace("[[EmailAddress]]", $person_message_row['PrimaryEmailAddress'], $message);
                $subject = str_replace("[[EmailAddress]]", $person_message_row['PrimaryEmailAddress'], $subject);

                mail($person_message_row['PrimaryEmailAddress'], $subject, $message, $headers);

                $MessageCount += 1;
            }

            mysqli_free_result($select_result);

            return $MessageCount; // <------- This number returns the correct count.

        } else {

            mysqli_free_result($select_result);

            return 0;

        }

    } else {

        mysqli_free_result($select_result);

        return 0;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some possible walk-through are listed below it might help.

1. Check if all the email address are valid that are stored in db.
2. Check the spam folder on your respective email accounts.
3. Put your code in `try {} catch(Exception $e) {}`, see if provides some help.
4. Before sending mail just write data to a file and see if everything comes ok.

With these you might find something to move on.

Comment: Thanks, @Franky, I tried the file option #4 and I do get two writes. Nothing comes in on the spam folder after the first message.